# AFMotion Post with Token

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rubymotion, warden

I've got a Sinatra/Warden Remote API, and a client in RubyMotion.
How can I post the Authentication Token and User Object with AFMotion for initial registration (from client)?

This more or less what I have so far, not much I know.
Basically I need to pass through a token to the remote api and a user object.

```
  def register_user(user)
      @client = AFMotion::Client.build("http://localhost:9393/register") do
          header "Accept", "application/json"
          request_serializer: :json
          response_serializer :json
      end
  end
```

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the line you initiate `@client` object to something like this

```
    @client = AFMotion::Client.build("http://localhost:9393/") do
      header "Accept", "application/json"
      response_serializer :json
    end
```

and when you want to do a POST request, you can do

```
    @client.post('register', {
        token: 'TOKEN HERE',
        user: 'USER OBJECT HERE'
    }) do |result|
        puts result
    end
```

You can find out more [here](https://github.com/usepropeller/afmotion#http-client).

Comment: Thank you very much attomos. Sorry - can you explain the code? should it not be something like this - http://pastebin.com/74hAwG4Q

Comment: Sure, @DaneBalia. Your code is correct. But in my answer, I just write excerpt of the complete code. I just make some changes. You should see the full code now.